# Después de eliminar algunos archivos que obtengo por ftp de mi servidor Django cuando los vuelvo a consultar se genera un error

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Estoy utilizando Django para descargar desde un servidor FTP algunos archivos mp4 por medio de 2 input en una pagina html, por ejemplo:

**Nombre:** Jorge

**Apellido:** Mario

Entonces utilizando ftplib en mi view voy y busco en el servidor ftp el archivo que se llame "Jorge_Mario.mp4" y lo descargo en mi servidor para posteriormente mostrarlo en una modal (pop up).

El problema es que estoy haciendo una view con el objetivo de eliminar los archivos que se almacenan en mi servidor, para que al momento de recargar la pagina se eliminen. Pero después de hacerlo voy a consultar nuevamente algún archivo del servidor y me manda la excepción : *No such file or directory* y al cabo de un tiempo recargo la pagina nuevamente y consulto y esta vez si lo hace normalmente, el problema es después de eliminar los archivos.

View que carga el video:

```
@csrf_exempt
def MostrarVideo(request):  

    nombre =  request.POST['nombre']
    apellido =  request.POST['apellido']
    filename = nombre + apellido + ".mp4"
    import ftplib

    ftp = ftplib.FTP('dirser', 'user', 'pass')

    ftp.dir()

    try:
        with open("videos/"+filename, 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+filename ,f.write)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error " + str(e)
        return HttpResponse(0)
    print ("Enviando")
    return HttpResponse(filename)
```

Script donde recibo el archivo para abrir la modal y mostrarlo

```
$.post("/MostrarVideo/", {"nombre":$('#nombre').val(),"apellido":$('#apellido').val() }, function(json){
        if(json != null && json != undefined && json != ""){

            if (json!=0 && json!="0"){

                $('#ifrm').attr('src', "videos/"+json);
                $('#nombre').val('');
                $('#apellido').val('');

            }else{
                $('#Modal-video').modal('toggle');

                var mos;
                mos = $("h3");
                mos.text("Ha ocurrido un error, verifique el nombre y apellido");
                mos.css("background-color","#f2dede");
                mos.css("color","#000");
                mos.css("border-radius","10px")
            }
        }
      });
    });
```

View en la que elimino los archivos

```
@csrf_exempt
def Eliminar(request):
    try:

        directory = "videos"
        os.chdir(directory)
        file = glob.glob('*.mp4')
        for filename in file:
            os.unlink(filename)
        return HttpResponse("ok")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("error")
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado cargar el video en un Buffer?

Comment: @GermanAlzate No se me había ocurrido, pero no sé como hacerlo, tienes alguna guía de la que me pueda instruir para poder resolver mi problema? Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas acerca de los buffers, y de la libreria de [io](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) de python, para que sepas como debes proceder, la idea no es guardar los archivos en el servidor si no mantenerlos en la memoria solo el tiempo necesario, luego se desechan